# How to fix the setter of the fullName property to enable an automatic update for the firstName and lastName properties?

Tags: ios, swift

I have to create a class Person with the following Properties: + firstName: String + lastName: String + fullName: String. The fullName property has a getter and setter. The getter returns a String that combines the firstName and the lastName property like this "firstName lastName". The setter has a String as an input value that contains a first name, a space character and a last name, such as "firstName lastName".  The setter is supposed to do parsing of the string  so that the firstName and the lastName properties are set correspondingly after I set the fullName property.

Something is wrong with my setter for the fullName. How should I change it?

```
class Person {

    var firstName: String            
    var lastName: String        
    var fullName: String {            
        get {                
            return "\(self.firstName) \(self.lastName)"                
        }

        set (newValue) {

            let fullNameArr = newValue.components(separatedBy: " ")

            if (fullNameArr.count == 3) {

                firstName = fullNameArr [0]
                lastName =  fullNameArr [2]                    
            }
        }
    }

    init (firstName: String, lastName: String){

        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName           
    }        
}


var person1 = Person (firstName: "Mark", lastName: "Miller")
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: I see just a "running" sign... No error messages....

Comment: What messages did you hope to see?

Comment: fullName is a computed property that contains 2 other properties  - firstName and lastName.  If I set a new fullName as a string with a character space, the values of firstName and lastName are supposed to be updated automatically.

Comment: Yes. I used the playground. It does not work with print either.  Swift is a new language for  me. I don't understand how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is basically right (though the setter for `fullName` isn’t handling anything other than `fullNameArr.count == 3`).

```
class Person {
    var firstName: String            
    var lastName: String

    var fullName: String {            
        get { "\(firstName) \(lastName)" }

        set {
            let names = newValue.components(separatedBy: " ")
            lastName = names.last ?? ""
            firstName = names.dropLast().joined(separator: " ")
        }
    }

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName           
    }        
}

let person1 = Person(firstName: "Mark", lastName: "Miller")
print("first:", person1.firstName, "last:", person1.lastName)

person1.fullName = "Mary Jane Watson"
print("first:", person1.firstName, "last:", person1.lastName)
```

On an iPad playground, for example, that yields:

[image]

Note, because I did this on an iPad, I have to tap on the little icon on the right to see the output.

---

If you want an additional initializer that takes a full name, go ahead and add one:

```
init(fullName: String) {
    let names = fullName.components(separatedBy: " ")
    lastName = names.last ?? ""
    firstName = names.dropLast().joined(separator: " ")
}
```

---

Note, the above includes any middle names as part of the first name. If you really wanted to discard middle names, just grab the first name (after dropping the last name) like so:

```
let names = newValue.components(separatedBy: " ")
lastName = names.last ?? ""
firstName = names.dropLast().first ?? ""
```

---

Personally, I’d use `struct` rather than `class`, as we should generally use value types unless you explicitly need reference semantics. That also eliminates the need for the `init` method, as it will create that for us.

```
struct Person {
    var firstName: String            
    var lastName: String

    var fullName: String { "\(firstName) \(lastName)" }
}

var person1 = Person(firstName: "Mark", lastName: "Miller")
print(person1)
```

Yielding:

[image]

As you can see, I also eliminated the `fullName` setter given the ambiguity regarding what to do with middle names, prefixes (like “Dr.”), suffixes (like “M.D.”), etc. But you can do whatever you want.